# Converting href perl variables to normal scalar variables

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I have these two variables that I am trying to compare. They both have the same value, however, one is a href variable - meaning, it's being read from a file like this

```
<a href=http://google.com>Variable</a>
```

It's read like this, but displayed as an anchor tag in the browser, so when I go to compare a value using `print "$collect_zids{$key} --> $temp";`I see in the browser as

Variable --> **[Variable](http://google.com)**

[How it appears in the browser. One text another link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Yt0.png)

I'm assuming these two values are different hence why this code does not run

```
if($collect_zids{$key} eq $from_picture){
    print "<h1>Hello</h1>";
}
```

Is there a way I can convert the href variable into a normal scalar variable so that I can compare them?

Thanks!

P.S. I think Javascript might be the only way, however, I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: By "the same value" do you mean one has the value `"http://google.com"` and one has the value `"<a href=http://google.com>http://google.com</a>` - because those are **not** the same! Are you asking how to parse HTML in Perl so you can extract the text content of the `<a>` element?

Comment: By same value I mean, example - one is a scalar variable that has the value "Foo Bar". `$var = "Foo Bar";` and another is `$var2 = <a href=http://google.com>Foo Bar</a>`. So, if I was to print both of these in the browser using `print "$var - $var2"`, I would get `Foo Bar - Foo Bar`. But the only problem is, one is a text value and another is an anchor. So when I go to compare them using `if($var eq $var2){print "hi"}`, it doesn't return true.

Comment: Both are text values. One just has more text in it. Go and find an HTML parser library so you can extract the bit of text you care about from the HTML before you try to compare it to the other value.

Comment: I have added a picture in the question to show how it appears.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "href variable". You have two scalar variables. One contains plain text and the other contains HTML. Your task is to extract the text inside the HTML `<a>` tag from the HTML variable and to compare that text with the text from the plain text variable.

One way to do that would be to remove the HTML from the HTML variable.

```
my $html = '<a href=http://google.com>Variable</a>';
my $text = 'Variable';

$html =~ s/<.+?>//g;

if ($html eq $text) {
  say "Equal";
} else {
  say "Not Equal [$html/$text]";
}
```

But it cannot be emphasised enough that parsing HTML using a regular expression is very fragile and is guaranteed not to work in many cases. Far better to use a real HTML parser. [HTML::Strip](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Strip) is made for this very purpose.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use HTML::Strip;

my $html = '<a href=http://google.com>Variable</a>';
my $text = 'Variable';

my $parser = HTML::Strip->new;
$html = $parser->parse($html);

if ($html eq $text) {
  say "Equal";
} else {
  say "Not Equal [$html/$text]";
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that this is answered in the [Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-remove-HTML-from-a-string%3F)

> **How do I remove HTML from a string?**
>
> Use HTML::Strip, or HTML::FormatText which not only removes HTML but
>   also attempts to do a little simple formatting of the resulting plain
>   text.

**Update:** In a comment, you say

> I have no way of using these methods since I am not explicitly defining the variable.

Which is clearly not true. How a variable is initialised has no bearing whatsoever on how you can use it.

I assume your HTML text is in the variable `$from_picture`, so you would strip the HTML with code like this:

```
my $parser = HTML::Strip->new;
my $stripped = $parser->parse($from_picture);

if($collect_zids{$key} eq $stripped){
  print "<h1>Hello</h1>";
}
```

I have no idea where you got the idea that you couldn't use my solution because I was directly initialising the variables, where you were reading the data from a file. An important skill in programming is the ability to see through complex situations and extract the relevant details. It appears you need to do some more work in this area :-)

Comment: I am not defining the anchor tag within the same block I'm running my if condition. The anchor tag is being read from the file as mentioned in the question. Because it is a cgi script, when `<a href=http://google.com>Variable</a>` from the file, it only outputs Variable. I have no way of using these methods since I am not explicitly defining the variable. However, I appreciate your help. The Perl FAQ sent me in the right direction, so thank you for that!

Comment: @user3302134: *I am not defining the anchor tag within the same block I'm running my if condition* - I didn't say that you were. I just did it like that to make it easier to demonstrate what was going on. *The anchor tag is being read from the file as mentioned in the question* - I realise that. You made it very clear. But it has no impact on my answer. *I have no way of using these methods since I am not explicitly defining the variable* - That is not true.

Comment: I tried your first method and it did not work for me. However, I did not try with the `HTML::Strip` module since I am not using a private server, thus, that module is not installed. I trust that your second method works, however, because I had access to `HTML::FormatText` I used that method and wrote an answer for it.

Comment: @user3302134: My first method works. But unless you show us how you used it, we can't tell you what you are doing wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using the Perl module `HTML::FormatText;`

```
use HTML::FormatText;
my $formatter = HTML::FormatText->new();
my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_file("path_to_the_file"); #$string variable to hold the result and the path must be for a file.
```

After using the `HTML::FormatText` module, I was able to get the raw string that was being read, instead of it being interpreted as HTML. So, I was getting `<a href=http://google.com>Variable</a>` returned, instead of just `Variable`. After getting the raw string, I could use regex to extract the parts that I needed.

Credit to - https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FormatText

Comment: *I was able to get the raw string that was being read, instead of it being interpreted as HTML" - It's not a case of anything being "interpreted" as HTML. You have text that contains HTML mark-up. You need to remove that mark-up. That's what HTML::FormatText is doing for you (and HTML::Strip would have done exactly the same thing).